# Pino logger not including timestamp in the output in Node js

Tags: node.js, logging, pino

I configured pino with pretty-print to log calls in a Node js project to the console. Unfortunately, the output does not display the timestamp I configured. I am using pino version 8.17.2 and pretty-print version 10.3.1.  Here is my configured logger:

```js
         const levels = {
          http: 10,
          debug: 20,
          info: 30,
          warn: 40,
          error: 50,
          fatal: 60,
         };

         const logger = pino({
         level: 'info',
         useOnlyCustomLevels: true,
         customLevels: levels,
         transport: {
            target: 'pino-pretty',
            options: {
                colorize: true,
                colorizeObjects: true,
                translateTimestamp: "SYS:yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss.l",
                minimumLevel: 'info',
                timestamp: "SYS:yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss.l",
                levelFirst: true,
                ignore: 'pid,hostname',
                levels: levels,
            }
          }
      })
```

I use the log in this way:

logger.info('This is a log message') and output is which has no timestamp

```
INFO [18:06:00.159]: This is a log message
```

Comment: There is no timestamp option in the `pino-pretty`: https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty?tab=readme-ov-file#options

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it using             translateTime: "SYS:yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss.l",

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:
translateTime: "SYS:yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss.l",